# Grab dom attribute on event.target

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

Struggling with something which should be simple!  Have had a google, but struggling to get this to work.

I have an event handler, where when I click on a link, it returns/console.logs the DOM Node, I've clicked on.

For example:

```
<button class="toggle-btn toggle-btn-icon toggle-btn-open" type="button" aria-controls="toggle-i1-e1" aria-expanded="true">See more</button>
```

After I've clicked, I wanted to grab the entire value of `aria-controls`.

So I wanted to grab this value `toggle-i1-e1` separately and store this in a variable.

How do I do this?

Comment: yournode.getAttribute('aria-controls')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').getAttribute('aria-controls')
```

Or access it via event.target

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function onclick and then pass the event object. In the function use that event object to get the target and then get the attribute

```js
function getAttrs(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('aria-controls'))

}
```

```html
<button onclick="getAttrs(event)" class="toggle-btn toggle-btn-icon toggle-btn-open" type="button" aria-controls="toggle-i1-e1" aria-expanded="true">See more</button>
```